# How to send parameters to a thread and constantly check the progress of it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project i am having some static data, which i am getting them from some web services. they have some dependencies to another. 
 
Lets say 
from countries i am retrieving all of the cities and from cities i am retrieving all of the areas in the city. the dependency goes like that. while retrieving the data i am inserting them to their corresponding tables.
lets say I am about to update city table, i need a class to show me what is my current progress (the class should be something like below)

```
public class WhatIsMyProgress
{
   public int TotalItemsToBeChecked {set; get; } 
   public string CurrentProgressTitle {set; get;} 
   public int CurrentItemNumber {set; get; }
}
```

so when i want to update city table it goes like

```
 TotalItemsToBeChecked = ... // Total Number of Countries (lets say 214)
 CurrentProgressTitle = "UnitedStates"
 CurrentItemNumber = 4
```

So from this class i constantly can see whats the item in progress. 
i tried my best to explain my problem, let me know if i need to add more information...

Comment: [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: BackgroundWorker is bad advice since the introduction of the TPL!

Comment: if you are using .net 4.5 may be this will be useful http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx

Comment: IIS and multiple threads can be a bad thing. Do you expect all of the threads to complete by the time a client request ends? If you expect to keep threads active all of the time, you'll be up against IIS deciding to stop your application out of boredom or restart it after a configuration change.

Comment: The question has been answered here,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591697/is-it-good-idea-to-pass-the-progress-of-the-function-by-ref-values