# is it good idea to pass the progress of the function by ref values

Tags: c#

Few days ago i have asked a question about [how to constantly check the progress of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25528446/how-to-send-parameters-to-a-thread-and-constantly-check-the-result-of-it) but i have not receive any answer, so i tried to find a way to do it, so i made to ref parameters in my function which they return me the total number of items to be processed and the current processing item

```
public void SaveInfoToDBFromFiles(string path,ref int TotalItems, ref int CurrentItem)
{
  initialize the values;
  do some stuff;

  TotalItems=TotalNumberOfFiles;

  foreach(file in path)
  {
   CurrentItem++;
  } 
}
```

and in my UI, winforms , I make a thread  i have a progressbar which shows me the current progress of the function and the timer which updates the progressbar by getting the CurrentItem value,

```
        System.Threading.Thread th = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>   SaveInfoToDBFromFiles(path,ref Total,ref  Current));

        th.Start();
        progressBar1.Value=Total;
        timer1.Start();
```

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = Current;
    }
```

it works perfectly but im wondering whether is good idea or not ?

Comment: I think not - basically - it's not a thread safe solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in - what I think is - a much nicer way these days.

You can use the `Progress<T>` class and let the framework marshal it back into your UI thread.

Somewhat like this:

```
var progress = new Progress<int>(currentItem =>
{
    progressBar1.Value = currentItem;
});

await Task.Run(() => SaveInfoToDBFromFiles(path, progress);
```

Then you can just report the progress in the save method:

```
public void SaveInfoToDBFromFiles(string path, IProgress<int> progress) {
    // .. other code here ..
    var i = 0;

    foreach (var file in path) {
        progress.Report(i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

You could even wrap a custom type that holds more information:

```
// first, a class to hold it all
class MyType {
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public int CurrentItem { get; set; }
}

// .. then you need to declare the Progress instance to hold your type

var progress = new Progress<MyType>(myType => 
{
    label1.Text = myType.FileName;
    progressBar1.Value = myType.CurrentItem;
});

// then when you're reporting progress you pass an instance of your type
progress.Report(new MyType {
    FileName = file,
    CurrentItem = i
});
```

Comment: nice idea, but how can i get the total number of items ? i do not want to get it in UI.

Comment: alright for this issue i come out with an idea, i can report the percentage so i do not need to be worry about total number of items, but how can i pass the current processing file name to the UI?

Comment: `Progress<T>` accepts anything - my example is just an `int`. You could create your own custom type that holds whatever you want. For example, it could hold `Total`, `Current`, `Percent` and `FileName` values that you report from the method back to the UI.

Comment: am i thinking the more function is running it become slower ? actually im not so sure, but im thinking that in the beginning of async task it runs more faster.

Comment: There will be more references for the GC to collect - but it should get to them pretty quickly. If its an issue, just re-use your `MyType` instance each time you report progress.